# ZK-proof of usage in a seed of CSPRNG

Tags: random-number-generator, zero-knowledge-proofs

Assume a Player chooses a seed $s$ and he wants to prove that he uses it as a seed to CSPRNG function, where the seed is not public.
How can he prove it?

Thanks.